# asp.net AutoPostBack and update

Tags: c#, asp.net, drop-down-menu

Is there a way to have autopostback enabled and not have page refresh (thereofre scrolling back to the top) when a dropdownlist changes for example?
I have a few dropdownlists and the values in the subsequent ones need to change based on what is picked in the upper ones.
Whats the best way to do that? Each DDL is populated from the DB.

Comment: yes, it is called an update panel

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use an update panel to accomplish this. A full overview is provide [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386454.aspx) You add items to the panel that you need to post back and only that part of the page postbacks.

Answer (score 2):

You could maintain scroll position between postbacks pretty easily

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.maintainscrollpositiononpostback.aspx

Answer (score 1):

you can put all ddl into updatepanel,and then page will not postback itself.And your ddl can be rebind without needing a full page postback.
another option is to use cascading dropdown,there is a sample in asp.net ajax toolkit samples.It uses webservices for databinding.This methot is better than using updatapanels,but its little hard to implement.
http://www.asp.net/ajaxLibrary/AjaxControlToolkitSampleSite/CascadingDropDown/CascadingDropDown.aspx ,check this example.

Answer (score 1):

Us [Jquery AJAX](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) OR Simply Use ASP.net [UpdatePanel](http://www.asp.net/web-forms/tutorials/aspnet-ajax/understanding-asp-net-ajax-updatepanel-triggers) Control